# sed substitution - do not modify for a particular case

Tags: unix, sed, scripting

I have a file with many lines written like this -

```
random text
some info, command -task shoot and more info
some info, command -new_task shoot and more info
more info and shoot a lot
command -task shoot and some more info and shoot a lot
```

I want the first letter of `shoot` to be capital except for the case `command -* shoot`.

So after substitution my file should look like this -

```
random text
some info, command -task shoot and more info
some info, command -new_task shoot and more info
more info and Shoot a lot
command -task shoot and some more info and Shoot a lot
```

I have written the following script for this -

```
var="shoot";
sed -i "/-.*?${var}/ ! s/ ${var} / ${var^} /g" file;
```

This script works fine except for the case when `command -* shoot` and `shoot` are written in the same line. In this case I get the output as -

```
command -task Shoot and some more info and Shoot a lot
```

Both the `shoot` becomes capital in this case which is undesirable.
Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Comment: What characters may come after `command -`? Everything but space, or a specific set?

Comment: There is only a specific set of characters :  -task, -start_task and -end_task, but I was thinking of writing a more generalized form of the sed command. Anyway, what will be the solution if only these 3 cases are present?

Comment: I would probably do sth like `sed 's/shoot/\u&/g; s/\(command -[^ ]* \)Shoot/\1shoot/g' file`, but I'm not saying this is the best way of doing it

Comment: Thanks @oguzismail. This works perfectly and I cannot think of a better solution than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task seems to require some form of look-back, where each replacement is conditional on the previous two tokens (which must NOT match 'command -*'). As indicated above, simple global replacement on a single condition will not work for cases like

```
command -task shoot and some more info and shoot a lot
```

Given `sed` relatively strict flow, and lack of complex condition, variables, might be easier to leverage sed pipeline, and build this as a series of commands:

1. Encode each 'command -* shoot' to hide them from next step substitution
2. Global replace of remaining `shoot` (surrounded with spaces)
3. Restore the 'hidden' shoorts.

```
sed -e 's/\(command -[^ ]\+ \)shoot /\1@shoot /' -e 's/ shoot / Shoot /' -e 's/ @shoot / shoot /'
```

The 'hiding' is achieved by insert a `@` before the `shoot`.

The pattern for the command option (-*) can be adjusted for more restricted character set

Possible to combine the 3 '-e' into single script, and use extended RE, as per Jotne suggestion to simplify command:

```
sed -r 's/(command -[^ ]+ )shoot /\1@shoot /;s/ shoot / Shoot /;s/ @shoot / shoot /'
```

Comment: Looks correct.  You can use `-r` to avoid escaping, and you can join all action use `;` instead of `' -e '`, so you get `sed -r 's/(command -[^ ]+ )shoot /\1@shoot /;s/ shoot / Shoot /;s/ @shoot / shoot /' file`

Comment: Change `s/ shoot / Shoot /` to `s/ shoot / Shoot /g` to get more `shoot` on the same line. (may be present)

Comment: Thanks @dash-o. A similar solution is given by @oguzismail in the comments to the question. The following is his solution -  `sed 's/shoot/\u&/g; s/\(command -[^ ]* \)Shoot/\1shoot/g' file`